# get Laravel's store function unique ID

Tags: php, laravel

From the Laravel's documentation [(file uploads)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads), the store function 
will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name. 
My code for uploading and storing the file is:

```
$path = $request->file('headerimg')->store('images');
```

Now `$path` will look like this: `images/sCzDxJBUnkveRLdzfhsIA7hAS8RVfPDXuJjBPgzM.jpeg`.

How can i get the filename only(`sCzDxJBUnkveRLdzfhsIA7hAS8RVfPDXuJjBPgzM.jpeg`) so I can use it let's say in a database, because right now all i have is the full path.

I can do it with PHP's explode but this is not the case.

BTW, using `getClientOriginalName()` will return the original filename, which is redundant since laravel is storing files with a unique ID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the answer somewhere hidden in some forums.

After uploading, this will return the filename only(excluding the path):

```
$request->file('headerimg')->hashName();
```

Doc here [hashname()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$saveTo = 'images';
$path = $request->file('headerimg')->store($saveTo);
$filename = substr($path, strlen($saveTo) + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! its similar with explode which i will use it as a last resort. I want the filename only via laravel.